# Slim template can't be rendered on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1, slim-lang

I did update my application to Rails 4.1.10 and it works fine on my staging environment.

Now as soon as I deploy my App to production I get the following fatal error in one of my views:

```
F, [2015-03-26T18:12:21.159599 #4741] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (795: unexpected token at [[iI""$2a$10$2BUwvWEvQzm404VPpY71BO:ET'):
     5:     .row
     6:       .col-xs-8
     7:         h1 = search_highlight(@programme.title, params)
     8:         - if current_admin_user
     9:           i.fa.fa-edit
    10:           '
    11:           = link_to t('edit'), (admin_programme_path(@programme) + '/edit'), target: '_blank'
  app/views/programmes/show.html.slim:8:in `_app_views_programmes_show_html_slim__2487450803659794271_70344829653360'
```

The hint I get is very misleading and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here.

```
795: unexpected token at [[iI""$2a$10$2BUwvWEvQzm404VPpY71BO:ET'
```

Comment: Try to remove `'` from 10 line.

Comment: Ok I will try this. Can you explain why you think this could be a problem?

Comment: unexpected token ends to `'`. Probably this is some mistake in slim parser.

Comment: This was not the problem

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the issue was not directly related to slim at all. When I access `current_admin_user` then the cookies from the client were parsed and since I did upgrade my Rails app from 4.0 to 4.1 the cookies were stored in the old format and the default for Rails 4.1 is :json.

So changing the following setting from `:json` to `:hybrid` in `cookies_serializer.rb` did the trick

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :hybrid
```